# Howto Sync similar tables with different names between two SQL databases?

Tags: microsoft-sync-framework

Unfortunately I need to keep the names of the tables different on the server and the client databases, however they are similar in structure. So for example my server has a table called "customers" while the client has the very same table with the name "clients" ?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide the local Table Name and Remote table Name to the `DbSyncAdapter`constructor. Something like this

```
 DbSyncAdapter adapter = new DbSyncAdpater("localTableName", "remoteTableName");
```

then attach this Adapter to the Provider

```
DbSyncProvider provider = new DbSyncProvider(connection);
provider.Adapters.Add(adapter);
```

Please note that the context of Local and Remote table Names will change depending on how you set the Providers and Sync Direction in  `SyncOrchestrator`.